# Decimal Places Puzzle

Tags: sql, decimal

I have a Query that incorporates some calcualted fields.  The 'Total' Column produces a value with 2 decimal places but the Commission and Net_Receipt Columns have 4 decimal places despite the code looking exactly the same format.  Can anyone tell me why and how to correct the latter two to 2 DP's.

```
SELECT `exhibition_sales`.`name`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.`category`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.`catologue_number`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.`title`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.`quantity`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.`unit_price`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.`commision_rate`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.quantity * `unit_price` AS `Total`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.quantity * `commision_rate` * unit_price AS `Commision`, 
       `exhibition_sales`.quantity * `unit_price` - `quantity` * `unit_price` * `commision_rate` AS `Net_Receipt` 
FROM   exhibition_sales 
ORDER  BY `exhibition_sales`.`name` ASC
```

[image]

Comment: The number of decimals should be handled in the presentation layer. Database gives out numbers, not formatted data. There may be definitions for precision in the database but that doesn't change where the presentation should be done. Most likely the column definitions have different precisions but you haven't shown them.

Comment: I'm not sure there is really a question here.  If you are losing _precision_ (i.e. if data is being truncated etc.), then it might be cause for concern.

Comment: Answer below. Besides: Please don't store currency in a numeric. It will always fail. Don't pretend to yourself it doesn't. Store the lowest unit, that is: cents, as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for the output format of decimal places is very convoluted.  If you want a particular number, then just cast to the format you want:

```
select . . .,
       cast(`exhibition_sales`.quantity * `commision_rate` * unit_price as decimal(10, 2)) AS `Commision`, 
       cast(`exhibition_sales`.quantity * `unit_price` - `quantity` * `unit_price` * `commision_rate` as decimal(10, 2)) AS `Net_Receipt`
```

There is some explanation in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html).

Comment: Many thanks Gordon that has saved me a lot of time and works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SQL-Server, the [rules of multiplication and division with numerics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/03/29/multiplication-and-division-with-numerics/) apply:

- `Total` is the multiplication of a (x, 0)-value with a (x, 2)-value, so the final scale will be 0+2 = 2. Hence `5 * 2.00 == 10.00`
- `Commission` is the multiplication of a (x, 0)-value, a (x, 2)-value and a (x, 2)-value so the final scale will be (0+2)+2 = 4. Hence `5 * 2.00 * 4.00 == 40.0000`
- `Net_Receipt` is the sum of two multiplications; the final scale will be max(s1 + s2, s3 + s4), that is `max(0 + 2, 2 + 2) == 4`. Hence `5 * 2.00 + 1.00 * 3.00 == 13.0000`

Comment: I did see this connection but could not understand why so thanks for the full explanation.  It does raise the question if this is progressive the more and more complex the multiplications become!  Thanks for your reply it is appreciated